# how these printf giving output any value? the functions aren't returning anything

Tags: c, function, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun1(void);
int fun2(void);
int fun3(void);
int x;  //global variable

void main(){
    x=10;
    printf("x = %d\n",x);
    printf("x = %d\n",fun1());
    printf("x = %d\n",fun2());
    printf("x = %d\n",fun3());
}


fun1(void){
    x = x+10; //global
}

fun2(void){
     int x;
     x = 1;  //local
     return x;
}

fun3(void){
    x = x+10;  //local
}
```

Output:

```
x = 10
x = 20
x = 1
x = 30
```

Comment: Your code has some bugs, so it's not surprising it doesn't do what you expect. Fix the bugs and the mystery will go away.

Comment: Hello undefined behavior. Turn on compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang)

Comment: What did you expect would happen?

Comment: By using `%d` in your format string, you have promised `printf` that an integer will be passed.  Since you aren't returning anything, you've broken that promise.  However, `printf` has no way of knowing that.  It will look in the memory location where the integer SHOULD be (but isn't), and print whatever else happens to be in that location, which can sometimes be predicted.. but never should be.  What you've done here is just broken code.  The arguments passed to `printf` have to match what's promised in the format string, or weird behavior will occur.  Just don't.

Answer (score 1):

In a typical C function, the arguments that will be passed are known at compile time.  They are declared in the function definition and in the function declaration (if any).

The compiler generates the code based on this, and does compile-time checks so that if you were to pass an unexpected argument or one of the wrong type, the compiler will notice and output an error or a warning.

But `printf` does not work like that.

Functions like `printf` are capable of working with different numbers and types of arguments each time they are called, without knowing what these arguments will be at the time they are compiled.

These are called `variadic` functions and instead of declaring their arguments explicitly, they use macros such as the`va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end` in order to fetch the arguments at run-time.  Here's the man page for those macros:

https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg

By using `%d` in your format string, you have promised the `printf` function that an integer will be the first argument you pass following the format string.  But in your code, you have not done that.  Your code breaks the promise that it made to `printf`, but `printf` has no way of knowing.. it will just use the `va_arg` macro to grab an integer value from the memory location where it should be.

Since you haven't put the integer where it should be, the value it grabs will be whatever happens to be in that memory location, which could be complete garbage.

In the C specification, this is what's referred to as "Undefined Behavior".  It means simply, that doing this is just not supported, and the C language makes no guarantee at all as to what will happen if you do it.

In higher level languages, for example in Python, there is more run-time checking and the print functions can determine at runtime how many arguments you passed and their type.  But not in C.  You have to make sure that the number and type of arguments that you pass to `printf` perfectly match those indicated in your format string, and in the same order.

In your code, since your format string indicates that an integer will be passed, but you don't pass an integer, you can't expect it to work correctly, it's just "undefined behavior".